# execute alias in alias

Tags: linux, alias, csh

I have the following aliases and I want the second alias to execute the first alias.
what happen that the second alias not detect the $unit.
How can I make it work?

```
alias unit "`set unit = grep top def.tcl | tail -1 | item 2`"
alias ipcd 'unit ; cd flow/$unit/ip/'
```

Comment: What shell is this? Anyway, use a function.

Comment: I use csh, I don't familiar with function but tried the below without success...
`function unit() {
 set unit = a 
 }
`

Comment: csh doesn't have functions; one reason people recommend against using csh.

Comment: Is it a smart way to that in csh?

Answer (score 0):

You're command-substituting `set`. Variables set inside command substitution blocks are discarded after expansion. What you want is command-substitute `grep top def.tcl | tail -1 | item 2`:

```
alias unit "set unit = "\""`grep top def.tcl | tail -1 | item 2`"\"""
alias ipcd 'unit ; cd flow/$unit/ip/'
```

If you want to make it a function, set the following in your `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc`:

```
alias function 'set argv = ( \!* ) ; source ~/.cshfuncs'
```

Then add your functions to `.cshfuncs`:

```
# Functions for C Shell.

set ret = -1
onintr exit

switch ("$1")
  case "ipcd":
    set unit = "`grep top def.tcl | tail -1 | item 2`"
    cd "flow/$unit/ip/"
    set ret = 0
    breaksw
  case "myfunc":
    echo "A function."
    set ret = 0
    breaksw
  default:
    echo "Function $1 not set."
endsw

exit:
set argv
exit $ret
```